# How to justify this rule stated by Symbolab Calculator : $f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{g(x)\times ln(f(x))}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, logarithms, exponentiation

The rule Symbolab Calculator uses to solve $\sqrt[x]{x^3} = 100$ is not familiar to me and I do not think I have already seen it featuring in any usual exponent/ log  rules list

The rule is as follows : $f(x)^{g(x)}  = e^{g(x)\times ln(f(x))}$

Is the rule related to the fact that a number , say, $a$, can be expressed as

$e^{ln_e(a)}$ ?

To which ordinary rule can the rule used by Symbolab be reduced? If it can't , how can it be proved or explained?

[image]

Comment: $f^g = (e^{\log_e f})^g = e^{(\log_e f)\times g}$

Comment: You do want to assume $f > 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the rule related to the fact that a number , say, $a$, can be expressed as
>
> $e^{ln_e(a)}$ ?

It is **precisely** this rule at play, yes. You can use this rule with functions as well:

$$f(x) = e^{\ln(f(x))}$$

Moreover,

$$f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{\ln \left(f(x)^{g(x)} \right)}$$

and, using the property that $\ln(a^b) = b \ln(a)$,

$$f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{g(x) \cdot \ln(f(x))}$$